# FTP Connection/Instantiation Hangs Application

Tags: python, ftp

I am attempting to open a connection via FTP using the following simple code. But the code is just hanging at this line. Its not advancing, its not throwing any exceptions or errors. My code is 6 months old and I've been able to use this code to connect to my website and download files all this time. Today its just started to hang when I go to open a FTP connection.

**Do you know what could be going wrong?**

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP("www.mySite.com")  # hangs on this line
print("Im alive") # Never get printed out
ftp.login(username, password)
```

I administer the website with a couple of other people but we haven't changed anything.

**Edit:** Just tried to FTP in using `Filezilla` with the same username and password and it failed. The output was:

> Status:   Resolving address of www.mySite.com
>   Status: Connecting to IPADDRESS...
>   Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>   Error:  Connection timed out
>   Error:  Could not connect to server
>   Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Status: Resolving address of www.mySite.com
>   Status: Connecting to IPADDRESS...
>   Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>   Error:  Connection timed out
>   Error:  Could not connect to server

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have server issues, but if you'd like the Python program to error out instead of waiting forever for the server, you can specify a timeout kwarg to `ftplib.FTP`. From the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP)

> class ftplib.FTP([host[, user[, passwd[, acct[, timeout]]]]])
>
> Return a new instance of the FTP class. When host is given, the method call connect(host) is made. When user is given, additionally
>   the method call login(user, passwd, acct) is made (where passwd and
>   acct default to the empty string when not given). The optional timeout
>   parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking operations like
>   the connection attempt (if is not specified, the global default
>   timeout setting will be used).
>
> Changed in version 2.6: timeout was added.

Comment: I am surprised that there is not a default timeout.  There is one when using the Paramiko ssh library.